# Mathematical expression for or approximation of $ 100 \sum_{n=1}^m(\zeta(2n)-1)$, for positive $m$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, approximation, riemann-zeta

`m:  sum:
1 64.4934066848226436472415166646025189218949901206798437735
2 72.7257300559364627988418863187193091993700853125525345418
3 74.4600362543813767702936792978113619895518343158378907260
4 74.8677718741758107081622031486766085154479133808228927590
5 74.9672293869576192418767990387085102160498665372706444847
6 74.9918380422884240717405988434824773120914753830709849380
7 74.9979628557942945546664533539960106868396449999864398863
8 74.9994910817351597418397105027596828891633838990335930016
9 74.9998728110616597258253566672218768622088536209289261159
10 74.9999682072650470054366718710902217968032330396699856909
11 74.9999920523153197787356722359088970962967372218479515179
12 74.9999980131342249046836334799296906764194876137316817975
13 74.9999995032897077411877569457803537462823740925484703886
14 74.9999998758231102200334624277007555865246973818543999697
15 74.9999999689558534620002807148772290886466787386499136513
16 74.9999999922389717987653356348917888480516289869481421044
17 74.9999999980597438866680365241354748371579344042604025661
18 74.9999999995149360757722349477284380616897765026412919785
19 74.9999999998787340305101000667521616972771038539058948170
20 74.9999999999696835089127389595774928811465947292918949161`

By approximation from [this online regression tool](http://www.xuru.org/rt/NLR.asp#Manually) I've been able to generate:  $$y=74.75560361 + \frac{4.829026118}{x} - \frac{19.87124992}{x^2} + \frac{4.776049777}{x^3}$$

This is important because it would provide a "more reasonable" object on which to perform calculus and elementary algebra on. It would also save quite a bit of time computationally. I am aware of the limit as $m$ goes to infinity, that's just the infinite sum. I am looking for something that calculates the partial sum well.

Comment: The limit as $m$ goes to infinity of the sum in question, without the factor of $100$, is $3\over4$, according to  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function#Infinite_series Wikipedia cites http://empslocal.ex.ac.uk/people/staff/mrwatkin//zeta/borwein1.pdf , but I didn’t look closely for that particular result. Maybe something in that paper will help you if you need approximations of the finite sums.

Comment: Hint: write $\sum_{n=1}^m (\zeta(2n)-1) = \sum_{n=1}^m \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^{2n}} = \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \sum_{n=1}^m \frac{1}{k^{2n}}$. Now the inner sum is a geometric series (which if m -> infinity has a really nice form) so it should be workable from here